# Passing a pointer to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm working on a function that needs to recursively call itself to calculate F(N). I'm designing an efficient recursion that memorizes previously called recursive terms. Unfortunately I'm running into a problem with passing my array into a helper function where the recursion happens. here's the code:

```
int task_1(int N){  
int res;
if(N<0) //if N is less than 0, return 0 and print bad input msg
{
    printf("Bad Input, N was less than 0: Try again\n");
    return 0;
}
int* rec_arr=(int*)calloc(N, sizeof(int));

int i;
for(i=0; i<N; i++) //filling array with incorrect values to edit when new values are written in
{
    rec_arr[i]= -1;
    //printf("%d", rec_arr[i]);
}
//printf("pre: %d\n", res);
res = task_1_helper(N, rec_arr);

//printf("post: %d\n", res);
return res;

}

int task_1_helper(int N, int* arr) //this is the helper function that computes      recursive calls
{


int rem=(N%2); //remainder check for even/odd
int res; //result integer being returned
if(N==0)
{
    res= 0; //if N=0, return base case  
    arr[N]=res;

    return res;
}
if(N==1)
{
    res = 1; //if N is 1, return base case
    arr[N]=res;

    return res;
}
//printf("%d",arr[N]);
if(arr[N]!= -1)
{
//      printf("THIS IS FUCKING SHIT UP:N|%d| arr[N]: %d\n",N,arr[N]);
    return arr[N];  
}   
//printf("THIS WORKS\n");
//  printf("N: %d, rem: %d\n", N, rem);
if(rem==0) //if N is even, return even recursive term
{
    printf("HUHUHU");
    res = ((task_1_helper((N/2), arr))+(task_1_helper((N-2), arr)));
}
else //if N is odd, return odd rec term
{
    printf("WAWAWAW");
    res = task_1_helper(((N+1)-2), arr);
}
//return 0; should not be necessary
arr[N]=res;
return res;


}
```

What is happening when I call this function, is that my array(which will be passed filled with N elements, all -1) is reset to all 0 values once passed. I believe I understand the problem, which is that my reference to the array is not being passed into my helper function properly.

I don't know exactly where I can fix this problem or how. but I'd love some help with the pointer issue. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: task_1 calls task_1_helper with int N and int *rec_arr
rec_arr is an array filled with -1

task1_helper replaces rec_arr[N] with 0 or 1
if rec_arr[N] is not -1 you want to return the value of arr[N] that is 0 or 1
 but you get only 0

Is this correct ?
How do you call task_1 ?

Comment: The question references a runtime problem.  so the posted code needs to cleanly compile.  The posted code is missing #include <stdio.h>, #include <stdlib.h>, and #include <string.h>    The posted code is also missing the prototype for the function: `task_1_helper()`.  The posted code is also missing an appropriate main() function to drive the rest of the code.

Comment: in C, the returned value from malloc(), calloc(), and realloc() is `void*` type, so can be assigned to any other pointer.   The cast'ing of that returned value only clutters the code and will be a real headache when debugging and/or performing maintenance.   When calling any of these 3 system functions, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this line: `arr[N]=res;` is accessing beyond the end of the array bounds.  This results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: The profanity in the code is very unprofessional.  (and will get you fired)

Comment: this line: `int* rec_arr=(int*)calloc(N, sizeof(int));` has a few problems.  Besides casting the returned value, not checking for function failure, when 'N' is 0, the call to calloc() will fail/return a NULL pointer. Then any assignment statements like: `arr[x] =` will result in a seg fault event

Answer (score 2):

Before we get to the problem, [I hate to be pedantic but ...] here's a few stylistic tips that can help:
Indent cleanly
Don't use "sidebar" comments -- put them above the line they're on
Don't use "all caps" for a variable -- that's reserved for `#define's`
Don't use *multiple* "non-standard" returns in a function

I had to do three passes of cleanup on your code, just so I could see enough of your logic [and I've been writing C for 35+] to be able to see the problem.

Anyway, your problem is *not* that the array reference is being passed incorrectly--it is fine.

The problem is that in `task_1` you're doing:

```
res = task_1_helper(N, rec_arr);
```

What you want is:

```
res = task_1_helper(N - 1, rec_arr);
```

In other words, the *first* call was indexing past the end of the array and *always* invoking your "profane" if statement.  So, you *never* got to the point of any recursion.

**UPDATE:**  In `task_1`, if you set `rec_arr[0] = 0;` and `rec_arr[1] = 1;` *before* you call `task_1_helper`, you can remove the first two if statements in `task_1_helper` (i.e. it becomes simpler and will run faster)